# What happens if one class has many categories?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective C, if a class has many categories in a single application,
Do we specify which category of class we want while instantiating ?

Answer (score 1):

All of the methods defined in all categories will be added to the class. This occurs at run-time and if there are two methods in different categories with the same signature it is undefined which method will be used, so there would be no point in specifying a particular category for any particular instantiation even if you could - all the instantiations will use the same method implementations anyway.

If you want to have methods that are only available to particular instantiations use a subclass instead.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify which category of class you want while instantiating. The method that category adds become the part of class. For example if you add method to `NSString` class then compile will expect an `NSString` instance to have in its repertoire.